# Single Click VNC with Windows

Tags: windows, connection, vnc, vinagre

I’m trying to help someone on a Windows machine. The irony is that I now need help myself to connect the 2 computers.

I open my Remote Desktop Viewer, put it in listening mode by selecting ’Reverse Connection…’ but nothing happens when the other side runs the One Click VNC executable.

My 5500 port is open so I find it hard to believe this is a forwarding problem.

Answer (score 1):

As [One-Click VNC](http://www.vncscan.com/vs/oneclickVNC.htm) uses default port 5500 to establish a VNC connection this is different in [Vinagre](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/vinagre.1.html), where port 5900 is used by default. You may run vinagre from the command line by specifying another port:

```
vinagre <IP_REMOTE>::5500
```

If you are still unable to establish a VNC connection you may need to change settings on the Windows side (or use another VNC server there, e.g. [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php))